# PyQt4 create windows that are unresizable

Tags: c++, python, qt, qt4, pyqt

For some reason, any widget I create using PyQt4 cannot be resized. When i try and resize the window with the mouse nothing happens. The following simple program reproduces this behavior on my machine:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QApplication
from sys import argv

app = QApplication(argv)
mw = QMainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

I usually develop using the C++ Qt libraries, where I would expect this to work. What's more an equivilent C++ application behaves in exactly the same way.

What could cause this?

Comment: `app.exec_(argv)` does not work. You already created `app` wih `argv`, so you should do `app.exec_()` (no arguments).

Comment: sorry, I was writing this from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution - it turns out I had broken my `compiz` settings in a rather... unique manner, which caused Qt apps to not resize correctly. Thanks to everyone who answered however!

Answer (score 0):

`mw.setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 480)` before exec.

it locates window on screen (firs two parametrs), resizes it (3 and 4 parametr) and enables resizing.